# Can i specify my own hangout ID to the new Google Hangout Buttons functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

Is it possible to use my own hangout ID (which I create using the calendar) for the new Google Hangout Buttons functionality? 
I render my buttons using Javascript:

```
<div id="placeholder-div"></div>
```

and:

```
<script>
gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div', { 'render': 'createhangout' });
</script>
```